# Collect unique values of array in an array React

Tags: reactjs

Can someone let me know how I can create a list of unique languages from an array inside another array.

This is the dataset...

```
const people = [
{
    //Other values, name date etc.
    languages: ["English", "Spanish"]
},{
    //Other values, name date etc.
    languages: ["English", "Mandarlin"]
},{
    //Other values, name date etc.
    languages: ["Japanese"]
},....
```

and here is as far as I've got....

```
const languagesOptions = this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
  new Map(
    ...item.languages.map(d => [d.languages])
  )
});
```

I can use the new Map function when it's not an array but can't get it to work with the languages data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map over it and use `Set` to remove dupes.

```js
const people = [{
  languages: ["English", "Spanish"]
}, {
  languages: ["English", "Mandarlin"]
}, {
  languages: ["Japanese"]
}];

const languages = [...new Set(people.flatMap(({ languages }) => languages))];

console.log(languages);
```